# neo4j Cypher Create relationship using proprieties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can create a relationship beetween multiple nodes using cypher.

I have object

A:{id:123, replyto:'', msg:"Hello All! Its Adam here"}
B:{id:32132, replyto:123, msg:"Hi Adam! Im Steve"}
C{id:4322, replyto:123, msg:"Hello! Ana here"}

D:{id:111, replyto:'', msg:"Hi"}
E:{id:222, replyto:111, msg:"Hi "}
F{id:3333, replyto:222, msg:"Here"}

So I want to create a Relationship "IS_A_REPLY" from nodes B and C to node A... how can I achieve this for multiple nodes? That is without having to declare this explicitly, since it's over one thousand nodes.

In psudocode

for allnode
if(nodA.id == nodeB.replyto) then 
create relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will depend a little on the nature of that id field that you have in your nodes there, but either:

```
MATCH (msg:Message) 
WHERE msg.replyTo IS NOT NULL
MATCH (origin:Message{id:msg.id}
CREATE msg-[:IS_A_REPLY]->origin
```

Or:

```
MATCH (msg:Message), (origin:Message)
WHERE msg.replyTo IS NOT NULL AND ID(origin)= msg.replyTo
CREATE msg-[:IS_A_REPLY]->origin
```

Comment: the id field is just a number

Comment: It matters whether it is the internal Neo id, or whether it is a field that you happened to have called id. If it's your data, use the first example. If it is the internal id, use the second.